# Extract unique value from a list of data frames into new data frame with indexing

Tags: r, list, unique

I have a list of data frames of the following structure:

```
cust_num   V2   V3 ...
```

Each data frame present a group of customers, where `cust_num` can appear more than once in a single data frame.

I want to extract the `unique` customers of each data frame and to insert them to a new data frame with `index` of the data frame (i.e., group) they came from.

Here is an example:

```
# df1

cust_num   V2   V3 ...
   1 
   1
   2 

# df2

cust_num   V2   V3 ...
   4 
   4
   5
```

and I want my result to be:

```
cust_num   group
     1       1
     2       1
     4       2
     5       2
```

I tried to use `for` loop, but I got troubles inserting the data into new data frame and create the group `index`:

```
for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
          x <- unique(df_list[[i]][1])
          new_df <- rbind(x)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `dat` is your list of data frames: `do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(dat), function(x) data.frame(cust_num=unique(dat[[x]][,1]),group=x)))`

Comment: @count you should add that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dat is your list of data frames:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(dat), function(x) data.frame(cust_num=unique(dat[[x]][,1]),group=x)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you can avoid a for loop by using the `dplyr` package to bind the data frames together while adding in that `index` column.

```
library(dplyr)

# Bind list of data frames into a single data frame.
d1 <- bind_rows(df_list, .id = "index")

# Remove duplicates.
filter(d1, !duplicated(d1))
```